# Alias to a double array from another byte array

Tags: c++, arrays, alias, type-alias

I am trying to create an alias to a double array from an array of bytes. But it happens to be behaving differently than I have expected.
The array of bytes stores - sensor code (int) followed by location data (double[3]). This is what I have tried

```
std::byte mSensorData[sizeof(int32_t) + 3 * sizeof(double)];
int32_t&  mSensorCode   = *((int32_t*)     &mSensorData);
double (& mLocation)[3] = *((double (*)[3])&mSensorData + sizeof(int32_t));

/* some code, byte* gpsData contains location data */
memcpy(mLocation, gpsData, sizeof(mLocation));

DEBUG(std::cout<<mSensorCode  <<std::endl;)
DEBUG(std::cout<<mLocation[0] <<std::endl;)
DEBUG(std::cout<<mLocation[1] <<std::endl;)
DEBUG(std::cout<<mLocation[2] <<std::endl;)

DEBUG(std::cout<<*((int*)&mSensorData[0])     <<std::endl;)
DEBUG(std::cout<<*((double*)&mSensorData[4])  <<std::endl;)
DEBUG(std::cout<<*((double*)&mSensorData[12]) <<std::endl;)
DEBUG(std::cout<<*((double*)&mSensorData[20]) <<std::endl;)
```

Result I got:

```
120
37.422
-122.084
16.6551
120
0
0
0
```

Comment: You break strict aliasing rules. use placement new?

Comment: What you are calling a type alias is actually called type punning (casting to a different type).  C++ doesn't really allow that except for in very specific and narrow cases, and this not one of those.

Comment: Are you making a precedence mistake? `(T*)x + k` is `((T*)x) + k`, not `(T*)(x + k)`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes I was, thank you - I managed to fix it.

Comment: Is this your own format or something dictated by a vendor?

Comment: It's my own data format, made for a hobby project on autonomous systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i cant comment on your post so i will add another answer :D.
That version works because now you are doing the conversion correctly.
The `mSensorData + sizeof(int32_t))` now will get you `sizeof(int32_t)` bytes to the right in `mSensorData` (notice that this happens because `mSensorData` is of type byte .. it's actually taking you `sizeof(int32_t) * sizeof(std::byte)` bytes to the right, but `std::bytes` has size 1).

It didnt work previously because `(double (*)[3])&mSensorData + sizeof(int32_t)` is a complitely different thing. first, the `&` has nothing to do there. you will end up with an address of the stack and start converting things on the stack. but even if that wasnt there, `(double (*)[3])mSensorData + sizeof(int32_t)` is still wrong. what this does is it converst `mSensorData` to an array of 3 doubles and then moves the pointer `sizeof(int32_t) * 3 * sizeof(double)` to the right. notice the difference? now your pointer is of type `double (*)[3]` so any arithmetic on it moves your pointer `3 * sizeof(double)` bytes

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside the issue of horrible aliasing violations, and the fact that you really, really cannot do this:

```
 (double (*)[3])&mSensorData + sizeof(int32_t)
```

Your intent here is to create an alias for `sizeof(int32_t)` bytes after the start of `mSensorData`.

However, this is not how pointer addition works in C++. After all, given the following:

```
 int *p;

 int *q=p+1;
```

`q` does ***not*** point to 1 byte after `p`. `q` points to the ***next*** integer after where `p` points to. On 64 bit platforms `q` points to 8 bytes after `p`.

Effectively, when you add something to a pointer, whatever gets added (and this includes subtraction) gets multipled by `sizeof` of whatever the pointer is pointing to.

Therefore, the result of the above addition is an alias to `sizeof(int32_t)*sizeof(double (*)[3])` bytes after the start of `mSensorData`.

In order to make the expected calculation you'll need to cast to `char *` first, perform the addition, and then cast to `double (*)[3]`.

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing seems a little too complicated. you just need to interpret the rest the buffer from `char*` to the type you need. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    int size = sizeof(int32_t) + 3 * sizeof(double);
    char data[size];
    memset(data, 0, size);
    data[0] = 1;

    int first_int = *(int*)data;
    double *doubles = (double*)(data + sizeof(int32_t));

    printf("%d %f %f %f \n", first_int, doubles[0], doubles[1], doubles[2]);
}
```

works just fine for me. `1 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000`

If you want to, you can use reinterpret_cast instead of the c style cast `double *doubles = reinterpret_cast<double *>(data + sizeof(int32_t));`, but it's the same thing you just reinterpret the buffer as a buffer of doubles instead of a buffer of chars

Comment: This is not portable and just happens to "work". The pointer `doubles` is most likely not aligned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Any Idea why this works ?
gps.h

```
#ifndef GPS_H
#define GPS_H

#include <cstddef>
#include <stdint.h>

class GPS
{
    std::byte mSensorData[sizeof(int32_t) + 3 * sizeof(double)];
    int32_t&  mSensorCode   = *((int32_t*)     mSensorData);
    double (& mLocation)[3] = *((double (*)[3])(mSensorData + sizeof(int32_t)));

public:
    GPS();
    int processData(const std::byte* gpsData);
    int getLocationData(std::byte* buffer) const;
};

#endif
```

gps.cpp

```
#include "gps.h"
#include "common.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <exception>

GPS::GPS(){
    mSensorCode = LOCATION;
}

int GPS::processData(const std::byte* gpsData){
    try {
        gpsData += sizeof(int32_t);
        memcpy(mLocation, gpsData, sizeof(mLocation));

    DEBUG(std::cout<<"Buffer Content"             <<std::endl;)
    DEBUG(std::cout<<*((int*)&mSensorData[0])     <<std::endl;)
    DEBUG(std::cout<<*((double*)&mSensorData[4])  <<std::endl;)
    DEBUG(std::cout<<*((double*)&mSensorData[12]) <<std::endl;)
    DEBUG(std::cout<<*((double*)&mSensorData[20]) <<std::endl;)

    DEBUG(std::cout<<"Data Content"             <<std::endl;)
    DEBUG(std::cout<<mSensorCode  <<std::endl;)
    DEBUG(std::cout<<mLocation[0] <<std::endl;)
    DEBUG(std::cout<<mLocation[1] <<std::endl;)
    DEBUG(std::cout<<mLocation[2] <<std::endl;)

    }catch(std::exception& ex) {
        DEBUG(std::cout << "GPS::processData ex:" << ex.what() << std::endl;)
    }
    return sizeof(mSensorData);
}

int GPS::getLocationData(std::byte* buffer) const{
    memcpy(buffer, &mSensorData, sizeof(mSensorData));
    return sizeof(mSensorData);
}
```

Result

```
Buffer Content
120
37.422
-122.084
0.0962061
Data Content
120
37.422
-122.084
0.0962061
```